# Is it possible to block all the VPNs by inspecting upper layer protocol field?

Tags: vpn

If one uses VPN, eavesdropper can not get any information in the IP packet header. However, at least he knows that the packet contains IP sec header by inspecting upper layer protocol field in the IP header.
Nowadays, lots of governments strive to strengthen their Internet censorship. Then, my question is simple. Why don't they just simply drop every packet that contains IP sec packet by inspecting upper layer protocol field? Are there different kinds of VPN using something to bypass that inspection?

Comment: Common sense please.

Comment: Not all VPN are IPSec. There are SSL based VPN, OpenVPN, various tunnel protocols, Tor with various hiding strategies, "not really VPN" like SOCKS proxies ... . While it is usually possible to detect and block these it is not that simple as you describe especially if there should be no false positives (i.e. blocking too much).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because VPN has massive legitimate uses as well, even in for instance China. International business requires communication, and VPN is used to provide communication.

China, Russia and most other countries want the money they generate from accepting business, so there's a fine line between making business use too difficult, so companies will stay away from the country - and blocking too little.

Comment: I don't fully share this view. If you are searching for VPN getting blocked in China or even specifically IPSec getting blocked you'll find numerous reports, even on vendor sites like Cisco. And the attempts to block Telegram in Russia with all its side effects of massive overblocking shows that a pro-business decision is not really guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

SSL VPN would be hard to detect as you will not be able to distinguish between a normal access to a secure site and the vpn unless you manage to break the tunnel.

IPSEC can be blocked and inclusively will not work well in NAT environments but I am not able to provide you an detailed explanation in English.